# drag and drop is not working properly(dnd_stop)

Tags: drag-and-drop, jstree, jstree-dnd

I am trying to drag and drop functionality by using jstree.This function is working fine but mouse pointer not dropping text. It's show pointer with selected text.
my question is, How to remove text with mouse pointer?

[image]

```
<select id="tableList" name="tableList" size="25" style="width: 223px;height:60px;"></select>                                 


$(document).on('dnd_stop.vakata', function (e, data) {
    var newOption = $('<option class="list-group-item" value="'+data.data.nodes+',">'+data.data.nodes+'</option>');
    $('#tableList').append(newOption);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been resolved. I have used `$(document).on('dnd_stop.vakata', (e, data) => {`  function two times and got the error from that on, removed one function, after that functionality is fine.